# How to store local date time in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using the version 2.0.0-rc8 of sequelize. When i stored the local date time, it always stores UTC date time. Is it possible to store local date time using sequelize?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString ?

Comment: @micnic I passed the local date time in query but it stores as UTC  in database.

Comment: It converts the local time to UTC

Comment: do not pass it as a Date object, pass it as a string, you can try `Date.prototype.toLocaleString()` or `Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()`, check the docs

Comment: userServiceAppointmentModel.update(
       { service_complete_time_by_technician: 2015-01-16 09:30:00 },
        {
            where: conditionalData,
            limit: 1
        })
        .complete(function (err, row) {
            if (err) {
                res.jsonp(responseError);
            }
            else {
                res.jsonp(response);
            }
        });

Comment: 2015-01-16 09:30:00 is my local time but it stores 2015-01-16 04:00:00 in database

Answer (score 10):

As others have already hinted in the comments, sequelize converts the date to UTC - this is by design, because it makes it easier for sequelize to work with, and to ensure that sequelize clients in different timezones will see the same timestamp.

In javascript the date will always be in the server's local time - this is a property of the javascript date object.

You can tell sequelize to store the date in a different timezone by using the `timezone` option:

```
new Sequelize(db, user, pass, {
  timezone: '+01:30'
});
```

This will save all dates with that timezone *and also assume that all dates currently saved in the DB are in that timezone*

Comment: Thank you so much. I read your blog on github, really appreciate your work. But i have a question i have 4 timestamp field in table. I want to store two of them as local time and rest of two as UTC. Can i define which columns to be UTC and which set be as local using the above timezone option?

Comment: @ Jan Aagaard Meier  The main problem is that different user stores their local times. So it is not possible to set timezone for all the fields. I want that  i passed a local string in query at it saves as it is in the database as we use in mYSQl

Comment: Short answer, no - the timezone option is global. Why do you need to store the user's timezone?

Comment: Because I don't want to parse or change the local date to or from  UTC. Different users stores their local time. So it is difficult to parse all the UTC time and convert to their local time while fetching records from the database.

Comment: I think we may be talking past each other. Sequelize (the server side) wants to store all times in the same timezone, to make it easier for itself. That does not mean you can't show the time to the clients in their own time zones - [timezones are a presentation layer problem](https://unix4lyfe.org/time/)

Comment: Jan thanks for your help. I found a solution. When i store local time in my localhost, It stores that local time into UTC. But the same code when i implement on my server i.e. in my Amazon server. It stores the local time which i passed. So the problem solved. I exactly wants the same. Once again thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should correctly store UTC time in mysql so that timezone is not needed.

For example, my mysql server is in timezone '+08:00', but if I change the timezone to '-05:00' the action will not break anything.

just use sequelize like this:

"mysql2": "^1.6.4",
"sequelize": "^4.41.2"

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, username, password, {
    host: hostname,
    port: port,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    dialectOptions: {
        typeCast: function (field, next) {
            if (field.type == 'DATETIME' || field.type == 'TIMESTAMP') {
                return new Date(field.string() + 'Z');
            }
            return next();
        }
    },
    operatorsAliases: false,
    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
    }
});
```